# Java Scanner - error al pedir datos por consola

Tags: java, consola, scanner

Agredecería puedan ayudarme con lo siguiente, en la primera imagen es donde pido por **consola** los datos a traves del Scanner hasta ahí bien, sin embargo en la siguiente imagen es donde tengo el problema. Donde **pido** que ingrese "los gigas de la memoria ram" al **insertar** solo un texto va bien pero si **inserto** 2 textos como "8" "GB", me salta los dos siguientes scanner los muestra juntos. Intente con next y nextline

.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código se comparte como texto. Replicar errores desde una imagen es bastante dispendioso.

Answer (score 2):

Intenta limpiar el scanner **sc.nextLine();** luego de pedir la "ram" con esto solucionas el salto de linea que se produce.

```java
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("Perificio");
       perifico = sc.nextLine();

       System.out.println("Ordenar");
       ordenador = sc.nextLine();

       System.out.println("Stock");
       stock = sc.nextInt();

       System.out.println("Precio");
       precio = sc.nextDouble();

       System.out.println("Ingrese la memoria ram");
       ram = sc.next();

       sc.nextLine();

       System.out.println("Ingrese procesador");
        procesador = sc.next();

       System.out.println("Ingrese la gráfica");
        grafica = sc.next();

    }
```

Comment: Por supuesto, gracias.

Comment: Funcionó, gracias por tu apoyo.

Comment: Con todo gusto.

Answer (score 0):

Lo recomendable en este caso es usar **nextLine** que te puede funcionar.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Ingrese la memoria ram");
   String ram = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Ingrese procesador");
    String procesador = sc.next();

    System.out.println("Ingrese la gráfica");
    String grafica = sc.next();

}
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, con los 3 datos como lo tienes en imagen ejecuta con éxito. Sin embargo al tener  la cantidad de scanner según la imagen que adjunto sigue el error.

Comment: Inténta con la segunda solución, agrega esa linea y me comentas como te va :), saludos.